# Redirect in Magento 2 from PHTML file

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, php, redirect

I want to redirect the user to specific page in Magento 2 from PHTML file.

In Magento 1 we use following method to redirect

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'?login=false');`
```

but not finding any solution for Magento 2.

I have also read this [blog](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/redirects-in-magento-2/) but it shows to create a custom module for that. 
As I don't want to do this from the module.

Please provide any solution if available.

**Edit**

I just want to redirect the user to the specific page if not log in for that to create module it will be a not a good thing.

Comment: Honestly, write a module. The template is not the right place for this. It should only contain most basic rendering logic

Comment: @DavidVerholen Can we do this without module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code in your phtml file....

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
$redirect->setRedirect('Your path....');
```

Comment: okey ... Happy Coding !!!! @RahulDambare

Comment: Its gives `The page isn’t redirecting properly` error when redirecting to homepage or `customer/account/login`

Comment: use abc/ ......instead of abc/index/index

Comment: For customer account login = > $redirect->setRedirect($this->getBaseUrl()."customer/account/login");

Comment: @RohanHapani, how to redirect to custom folder in root path with the params from phtml files?